# Links within jQuery autocomplete suggestion results?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to modify the results of list items so suggestions can be selected or clicked but also include a "Find More like this" link in the result after the text.

Currently the html produced by autocomplete renders the result as an anchor and sytantically putting an `a href` inside an `a href` seems like a no no.

Answer (score 0):

Use typeahead javascript from [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) by using

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
```

and filling the whole with jquery by adding

```
$('#myinput').attr('data-items', '3');
$('#myinput').attr('data-source='["One", "Two", "Three"]');
```